# Run a task on the background under a group name

Tags: linux, bash, nohup

My username on Unix is `xxx333` and I am part of a group named `doggroup`:

```
[xxx333@slowMachine ~]$ groups
doggroup xxx333
```

I would like to execute a task as a daemon (in the background) using `nohup` but not under my id, under the group id. I tried `sg`, this execute the task but not in the background:

```
[xxx333@slowMachine ~]$ sg doggroup -c 'nohup sleep 100'
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
```

How can I perfrom this task?

Comment: would the people willing to close the question give an explanation?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming at all and is better suited to superuser.

Answer (score 1):

Try to simply add a trailing `&` to the command

```
sg doggroup -c 'nohup sleep 100 &'
```

Without `&` a process is running in foreground (the default): in this case the `sg` command is simple waiting for `nohup` to terminate its execution to, in turn, return control to the shell.

Adding a `&` put the `nohup` process in background (so the control return to `sg` immediately).

`nohup` has 2 effects:

- the affected process become immune to SIGHUP signal (a signal sent to all sub-processes of a terminal when it starts to close);
- the stdout is redirected to a file just like a trailing `> nohup.out`

Comment: this does not work. Why would adding a trailing & would have given the correct effect?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel: i've add a simple explanation. The command works as expected in my environment, can you add extra details to debug your case?